# Transfer Tables from One Azure Datawarehouse to Another of Different Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

I want to transfer some tables from one azure datawarehouse to another azure data warehouse. But main problem is that both are under different azure subscription. Could anyone told me the source and target both are having different subscription in azure data factory will work or not?

Comment: Hi,If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that in Data Factory. It works.

Choose the new sink Azure datawarehouse from different subscription:
[image]

Hope this helps.